# Extraer contenido de campo MEMO en SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Tags: sql

La descripción de nuestros productos esta almacenada en el campo PartDescription de tipo VARCHAR MAX en la tabla T_Part. Al hacer la consulta para extraerla, trae campos MEMO, pero necesito la descripción en caracteres legibles para una persona.

[image: ConsultaYResultados]

Comment: ¿De qué tamaño puede ser una descripción que no quepa en 8000 caracteres? Eso es un problema de diseño y deberías cambiar la longitud del campo a algo decente antes de que surjan más problemas por lo mismo (principalmente de rendimiento).

Comment: Por otro lado, tu código no está trayendo un varchar(max) sino uno con longitud de 70. El problema, entonces, está en la interfaz gráfica que estás usando que convierte el texto en un tipo de texto largo.

Comment: @LuisCazares Con base en sus observaciones revisé los datos originales y encontré errores al momento de transferir los registros de una base de datos a otra. Gracias por su valioso aporte.